# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity

Alright, this question has been asked few times. But I can't get to find reason why i am getting this reason in my case. Here is how tables and code is set up.

```
public class ObjectA{
  public int Id;
  public virtual ICollection<ObjectB> Bs;
}

public class ObjectB{
  public int Id;
  public virtual ICollection<ObjectA> As;
}
```

POCO Mapping on B:

```
HasMany(As).WithMany(Bs).Map(ToTable("ObjectA_ObjectB_Mapping"))
```

There are 3 tables:

```
ObjectA
  Id (PK, Int) - AutoIncrement

ObjectB
  Id(PK, Int)  - AutoIncrement

ObjectA_ObjectB_Mapping
  ObjectA_Id
  ObjectB_Id
```

Here is new object is being inserted:

```
var a = new ObjectA(){}; --> This record already exist in table
var b = new ObjectB(){
  A = a; --> Just read only copy
};
```

When this insert is attempted then I get error about IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
When I look at SQL generated by EF, I can see that it is trying to insert value in field Id of ObjectB. It seems that there is something that wants to explictly wants to set this Id value. Something I am missing about how many to many relation is set??

Above code is just a very simplified pseudo representatiion, so you can skip comments about telling names, style etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why is `public int Id` a field on both objects?

Comment: Pseudocode, OK, but I don't understand `A = a;` while you only mention the many-many relationship.

Comment: @GertArnold "*Above code is just a very simplified pseudo representatiion, so you can skip comments about telling names, style etc.*" OP probably wrote this out of IDE, because I've seen three major problems with it that would totally screw EF over entirely.

Comment: @EBrown Yeah, I voted to close for not providing sufficient code. Also, it's lacking all kinds of relevant details, like code-first vs. db-first. It's probably just a mismatch between the store schema and the entity model.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is to [set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I suspect that's not the root problem here, and I wouldn't recommend doing that for obvious reasons, it's just bad practice.

It sounds like EF (or you) is trying to manage the ID's itself, rather than allowing SQL server to. I don't know why, I suspect your actual objects have things going on, but you can also attach the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` (in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace) to the `Id` column on your model to force EF to *not* create an `IDENTITY(1, 1)` column (or `AutoIncrement`, depending on DBMS), this creates the requirement for **you, the developer** to manage the `Id` column on that model entirely. (Before you can do *any* SQL operations you have to make sure `Id` is set properly, including `.Add`.)

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This will remove the `IDENTITY(1, 1)` constraint (or the `AutoIncrement`, whatever it is). You'll have to run a migration for this to take effect, but once it does you should not get this error anymore. You just have to be *very* careful to make sure you set `Id` on everything **before** calling `DatabaseContext.SaveChanges()` or `DatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync()`. (Whichever you are using.)

You should also explicitly define the `KeyAttribute` (from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`) on your `Id` columns.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Manipulating INSERT_IDENTITY will be the last thing I will ever look into because this is not the problem when these kind of errors happen. I tracked it down to real problem. Right thing to do is look at exception and then go down into Entries and see RelationManager. It has entries showing who are participants in hierarchy. From there I found that there was a relation coming into play with wrong settings. Once that relation was fixed, everything fell into place.

Comment: @ByteBlocks Maybe you should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: Mentioned what?